# CefSharp EvaluateScriptAsync - return result in a variable using visual basic language

Tags: javascript, vb6, cefsharp

I hope someone could help, I am trying to replicate this code but in visual basic language. I can't find some working example anywhere =( in the web, I managed to execute javascript code to press a button in the browser but no luck getting innerText from some td.
Thanks in advance.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        object EvaluateJavaScriptResult;
        var frame = chromeBrowser.GetMainFrame();
        var task = frame.EvaluateScriptAsync("(function() { return document.getElementsByClassName('mw-headline')[0].value; })();", null);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (!t.IsFaulted)
            {
                var response = t.Result;
                EvaluateJavaScriptResult = response.Success ? (response.Result ?? "null") : response.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(EvaluateJavaScriptResult.ToString());
            }
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

}
```

Comment: VB or VB.net? There's a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-to-vb.net tag for VB.net

Comment: VB!. Everything I've done so far I did it being guided by what I've found in VB Net but I am not an experienced developer so I can only get that far.. =´(

Comment: I've added the vb6 tag.